# Creating a interactive database using the excel files as a dataset with rows as field?

Tags: html, database, scripting, interactive

I would like to create an interactive database which gives the output of the columns with a header for the particular files called in the rows from the excel file. Could you help me out with the code?

Comment: Add your  existing code

Comment: I just used the template code from the andreasviklund.com for the database.